# PHP (XML TO ARRAY) Getting the attribute of the xml that is array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, json

Hello I am getting games in the spilgames xml. I managed to convert it to array but 1 problem came up again the problem is that the string I want to get is inside of an array or an attribute of 1 node xml .I can't get the attribute.

I want to get the attribute.

website of spilgames: *[here](http://publishers.spilgames.com/rss-3?limit=100&format=xml&category=Action)*

Code I have so far:

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://publishers.spilgames.com/rss-3?limit=100&format=xml&category=Action')); /* Get the xml */
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $games = json_decode($json); /* Make it an array */
    $game = $games->entries->entry;
    foreach($game as $entry) { /* Each game information */
        echo $entry->title;
        echo $entry->id;
        echo $entry->description;
        echo $entry->category;
        echo $entry->subcategory;
        echo $entry->technology;
        echo $entry->player->url;;
        echo $entry->thumbnails->small->url; /* Problems starts here */
   /* Because the thumbnails has 3 child but the info is inside of each child */
    }

?>
```

I am getting the xml not json in spilgames because I don't know how json works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would learn how JSON works because it will make your life easier:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://publishers.spilgames.com/rss-3?limit=100&format=json&category=Action');
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->entries as $entry) {
  echo $entry->title . "\n";
  echo $entry->id . "\n";
  echo $entry->description . "\n";
  echo $entry->category . "\n";
  echo $entry->subcategory . "\n";
  echo $entry->technology . "\n";

  echo $entry->thumbnails->small . "\n";
  echo $entry->thumbnails->medium . "\n";
  echo $entry->thumbnails->large . "\n";
}
?>
```